# No mapping found for field 'deleted' on class - Symfony

Tags: php, entity, symfony-3.4

I cant figure out where the error is coming from. Everything is set up:

```
trait SoftDeleteable
{
    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @ORM\Column(name="deleted", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $deleted;

}
```

and in my entity class:

```
use App\Base\Entity\Traits\SoftDeleteable;

 /**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deleted", timeAware=false)
 */
class User extends BaseEntity
{
    use SoftDeleteable;
}
```

and in config.yml

```
filters:
   softdeleteable:
      class: Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Filter\SoftDeleteableFilter
      enabled: true
```

When I try to update my database it throws:

> No mapping found for field 'deleted' on class 'App\Base\Entity\
>     t\User'.

Comment: Try to create the getter and setter on the trait. Also, whats that t\User ? You have a t folder?

Comment: It was a typo in a post. It worked! Thank you bro. @Elanochecer

Comment: You are welcome :)